# Untar subfolders with initial folder's content in linux

Tags: directory, tar

I have a directory, `/Landsat_Data/` which contains subdirectories (`Landsat_Data/Site1`, `Landsat_Data/Site2`, etc.). Each subdirectory contains `.tar.gz` files (e.g. `/Landsat_Data/Site2/LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735.tar.gz`, etc.) and each `.tar.gz` file contains tif or xml files like thisL

```
-rw-r--r-- espa/ie  29952 2016-01-07 14:57 LT50930861991021ASA00_sr_snow_qa.tif
```

What I want to do is to untar each tar file into its own sub-subdirectory (e.g. `Landsat_Data/Site2/LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735/`).

So far, I am using this command line while being the Landsat_Data directories:

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir tar -xvzf {} \;
```

However, this command extracts all the tif and xml files into each subdirectory (e.g. `Landsat_Data/Site2`) while I just want to untar the `LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735.tar.gz` to have a sub-sub-directory called `LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735` which contains all the tif and xml files. Any idea how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Could we see a sample of `tar -tvf` of a tar file? It also seems like your subfolder have a further folder structure, could we see a sample of that as well?

Comment: When you say "tar folder", you mean "tar *file*", right? Oh, and in the *nix world, we don't have folders, we have "directories" :)

Comment: @Zachary -rw-r--r-- espa/ie       59416 2016-01-07 14:57 LT50930861991021ASA00_sr_band5.tif
-rw-r--r-- espa/ie       29952 2016-01-07 14:57 LT50930861991021ASA00_toa_band6_qa.tif

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: @terdon I have tar directories which contains different tif files as shown in a previous comments. Just want to untar the directories while the files stay in the directories. Hope it is clear.

Comment: As I said before please *[edit]* your question and add the extra information. You are using "file" for everything and that is confusing. Ideally, show us an example of your directory structure and what you would like it to look like after extracting.

Comment: @terdon I tried to edit my questions. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Better, yes thank you. Let me see if I understand. What you want is to create a new subdirectory for each tar file and extract the tar into that subdirectory, right?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I want.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir tar -xvzf {} \;
```

according to `man find`

> -execdir command ;
>
> -execdir command {} +
>
> Like  -exec,  but  the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in
>                 which you started find.

Comment: Thanks. But this extracts the files contain in the tar-folder but I just want to untar the tar-folder while the files stay inside the untar-folders. Any clue how to do it?

Comment: @SimonB can you edit your post 1) with initial folder's content 2) intended extracted file ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way (this assumes you're using bash):

```
$ shopt -s globstar   
$ for tar in /Landsat_Data/**/*.tar.gz; do 
   tar xvzf "$tar" --one-top-level="$(dirname "$tar")"/"$(basename "$tar" .tar.gz)"
  done
```

The `globstar` option makes `**` match 0 or more files and directories recursively, so `/Landsat_Data/**/*.tar.gz` will match all `*tar.gz` files in any subdirectory of `/Landsat_Data/`. The `dirname` command prints the directory name of its input and the `basename` only the name with the extension you give it (here `tar.gz` removed. So, for example:

```
$ dirname /Landsat_Data/Site2/LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735.tar.gz
/Landsat_Data/Site2
$ basename /Landsat_Data/Site2/LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735.tar.gz .tar.gz
LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735
```

The `--one-top-level` is explained in `man tar`:

```
   --one-top-level[=DIR]
          Extract all files into DIR, or, if used without argument, into a
          subdirectory  named by the base name of the archive (minus stan‐
          dard compression suffixes recognizable by --auto-compress).
```

Taken together, this will do what you want.

---

If your `tar` doesn't have that option, you can do it manually:

```
$ shopt -s globstar   
$ for tar in /Landsat_Data/**/*.tar.gz; do 
    newdir="$(dirname "$tar")"/"$(basename "$tar" .tar.gz)"
    mkdir "$newdir"
    tar xvzf "$tar" -C "$newdir"
  done
```

Comment: Thanks terdon. I do have an error message though. ' unrecognized option '--one-top-level=/Landsat_Data/**/*'

Comment: @SimonB what operating system are you using?

Comment: I am on linux OS

Comment: @SimonB strange, maybe you have an older `tar` version. Anyway, see updated answer.